# Improving performance of cgi

Tags: python, cgi

I have 5 python cgi pages. I can navigate from one page to another. All pages get their data from the same database table just that they use different queries.

The problem is that the application as a whole is slow. Though they connect to the same database, each page creates a new handle every time I visit it and handles are not shared by the pages.

I want to improve performance.

Can I do that by setting up sessions for the user?

Suggestions/Advices are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

cgi requires a new interpreter to start up for each request, and then all the resources such as db connections to be acquired and released.

[fastcgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) or [wsgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wsgi) improve performance by allowing you to keep running the same process between requests

Answer (score 0):

Django and Pylons are both frameworks that solve this problem quite nicely, namely by abstracting the DB-frontend integration.  They are worth considering.